# Javascript - Insert array into another array with splice not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to create a Cache Hashtable in Javascript.

by executing `cache.splice(0,0, ...dataPage);` I insert my data form the first till the dataPage.length
position.

Let's say my dataPage size is always 10

My cache array should look like 
`[0: {..}, 1: {..} ..... 9: {...}]`

After that let's say I want to load the 5th page of data.
I'm executing `cache.splice(40,0, ...data);`

I'm expecting my array to look like 
`[[0: {..}, 1: {..} ..... 9: {...}, 40: {...}, 41:{...} ... 49{...}]`

But it looks like 
`[[0: {..}, 1: {..} ..... 9: {...}, 10: {...}, 11:{...} ... 12{...}]`

Any idea how I can achieve my expected result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache.splice(40,0, ...data)` means, that you `...data` will be inserted in at the 40th position of your `cache`.

If your `cache` doesn't have 40 elements, it cannot be inserted at that position.

Maybe you should first define a `cache` with the desired amount of positions and then splice your data into it.

**EDIT**
sure you can do it dynamically. Something like this (I didn't test it, but maybe you get the point):

```
var cache= [];
var insertion_pos = 40;
var dataPage = [0: {..}, 1: {..} ..... 9: {...}, 10: {...}, 11:{...} ... 12:{...}]

for(var i=0; i < insertion_pos; i++) {
   cache.push(i);
}

cache.splice(insertion_pos, 0, ...dataPage)
```

Comment: So isn't  there a way to expand my array dynamically in every insertion if needed?